# Prove or disaprove that proposition

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $l_1=(Cos\alpha_1,Cos\beta_1,Cos\gamma_1)$,$l_2=(Cos\alpha_2,Cos\beta_2,Cos\gamma_2)$,$l_3=(Cos\alpha_3,Cos\beta_3,Cos\gamma_3)$ \, three points that are perpendicular in the space ($l_1\perp l_2 \perp l_3$), and $u=f(x,y,z)$.
Prove or disaprove that $\\
$

$(\frac{\partial u}{\partial l_1})^2+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial l_2})^2+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial l_3})^2=(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})^2+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial z})^2$ $\\$
Where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial l_1}$ denotes the partial derivative of $u$ in the direction of $l_1$
$\bf{My\, attempt}$ $\\$

That are false, because, let $v_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}(1,2,3)$\, $v_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{27}}(-5,1,1)$ and $v_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{378}}(-1,-16,11)$ three perpendicular vectors in the space, and now if we use the fact that the derivative of $u$ in the direction of $l_1$ is the $\nabla f \cdot l_1$ where $||l_1||=1$
and get the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial l_1}$,$\frac{\partial u}{\partial l_2}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial l_3}$ and calculate the square  but i get that are diferent from the sum of the square of partial derivatives of $u$ respect the variables $x,y,z$.$\\$

I appreciate any correction on my disaprove or in it case the respective proof, is necesary comment that i try do the proof but i can´t and decide make a contra example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the directional derivative in direction of a unit vector $\vec v$ is (even though I do not like this notation)
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial\vec v} = \nabla u\cdot \vec v.$$
So, if $\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3$ are three mutually orthogonal unit vectors, we have
\begin{align*}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial\vec v_1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial\vec v_2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial\vec v_3}\right)^2 &= (\nabla u\cdot\vec v_1)^2 + (\nabla u\cdot\vec v_2)^2 + (\nabla u\cdot\vec v_3)^2 \\ &= \|\nabla u\|^2.\end{align*}

Comment: Y try one similar thing, but can you specifie that step when you manipulate the second equalty

Comment: This is just a standard result whenever you work with an orthonormal basis. One way to see it is to let $\nabla u = \vec x$ and let $A$ be the matrix whose columns are the $\vec v_j$. Then we're computing $\|A^\top \vec x\|^2 = (A^\top\vec x)^\top (A^\top\vec x) = \vec x^\top (AA^\top)\vec x = \|\vec x\|^2$, since $AA^\top = A^\top A$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks so much i don´t know these result,

Comment: Here's the intuition. You're doing a *rotation* of the standard coordinate system in $\Bbb R^3$. When you do this, although a vector obviously has different coordinates, its length doesn't change when measured in the new coordinate system.